# Update angular data on new SQL insert

Tags: javascript, android, mysql, angular

I'm planning on making a webservice where a data table will be displayed.

When the data inside the linked SQL database updates, or a new row is inserted, the angular should refresh the data aswell. The SQL query will be made via an android application.

Is it possible to create such a thing using angular/javascript? If not are there any viable alternatives?

Thanks